# Bit slicing with variable width in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to access certain sections of an array using the `+:` operator however getting the infamous `[variable] is not a constant` error. The only problem is, the width I would like the get from the array is changing as well.

This is the loop I have:

```
logic [N-1:0] a;
logic [2**N-2:0] b;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    a[i] = b[(2**i)-1 +: 2**i] == {(2**i){1'b1}};
```

In other words, if `N = 4`, I want this loop to do this:

```
a[0] = b[0:0] == 1'b1;
a[1] = b[2:1] == 2'b11;
a[2] = b[6:3] == 4'b1111;
a[3] = b[14:7] == 8'b11111111;
```

Logically, I'm pretty certain that the loop I provided works however SystemVerilog doesn't allow non-constants to be used for setting the width (after the `a:`).
How can I utilize the `+:` operator when my starting index and width are both dependent on a non-constant variable? or is there another way of doing this considering that `N` can be a large number.

Thanks!

EDIT:

This can be done with shifts, here is a working code:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    a[i] <= ((b >> (2**i)-1) << ((2**N) - (2**i) - 1)) == 
             {(2**N-1){1'b1}} << ((2**N) - (2**i) - 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `+:` with variable widths. It is actually just a short-hand for shifts and masks. For example, something like the following should work in your case:

```
  logic [N-1:0] a;
  logic [2**N-2:0] b;
  always_comb begin
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) begin
    logic [2**N-2:0] tmpb, tmp1;
    tmpb = b >> ((2**i)+1);
    tmp1 = ((2**N)'(1) <<  (2**i)) - 1;
    a[i] = (tmpb & tmp1) == 0;
   end
  end
```

you just need to figure out exact numbers of shifts and widths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of '+:` operator with a mask

```
   parameter N  = 8; localparam N2 = 2**(N-1);
   logic [N-1:0] a;
   logic [2**N-1:0] b;

   initial begin
      b       ={8'b000001,4'b1111,2'b01,1'b1};
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
          a[i]  = (b[(2**i)-1 +: N2] | ~N2'((1 << 2**i)- 1)) == '1;
      $displayb(a,,b);
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `+:` provided that the right hand side is a constant or `genvar`.

```
logic [N-1:0] a;
logic [2**N-2:0] b;
for (genvar i = 0; i < N; i++) begin : gen_a
    assign a[i] = b[(2**i)-1 +: 2**i] == {(2**i){1'b1}};
end
```

Note that this for-loop is a generate-for-loop which is not within a procedural block (ie `begin`-`end`)